# Why do HashSets not have a stable serialization?

Tags: java

Take a `HashSet` in Java. Put a string in it. Serialize it. You end up with some bytes - `bytesA`.

Take `bytesA`, deserialize it back as an `Object` - `fromBytes`.

Now reserialize `fromBytes` and you've got yourself another array of bytes - `bytesB`.

Strangely enough, these two byte arrays are not equal. One byte is different! Why?
Interestingly, this does not affect `TreeSet` or `HashMap`. It does however affect `LinkedHashSet`.

```java
Set<String> stringSet = new HashSet<>();
stringSet.add("aaaaaaaaaa");

//Serialize it
byte[] bytesA;
try (ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
  ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
  out.writeObject(stringSet);
  out.flush();
  bytesA = bos.toByteArray();
}

// Deserialize it
Object fromBytes;
try (ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytesA)) {
  try(ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(is)) {
    fromBytes = ois.readObject();
  }
}

//Serialize it.
byte[] bytesB;
try (ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
  ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
  out.writeObject(fromBytes);
  out.flush();
  bytesB = bos.toByteArray();
}

assert Arrays.equals(bytesA, bytesB); 

//array contents differ at index [43], expected: <16> but was: <2>
```

In case these help:
`xxd` hex dump of `bytesA`

```
00000000: aced 0005 7372 0011 6a61 7661 2e75 7469  ....sr..java.uti
00000010: 6c2e 4861 7368 5365 74ba 4485 9596 b8b7  l.HashSet.D.....
00000020: 3403 0000 7870 770c 0000 0010 3f40 0000  4...xpw.....?@..
00000030: 0000 0001 7400 0a61 6161 6161 6161 6161  ....t..aaaaaaaaa
00000040: 6178                                     ax
```

`xxd` hex dump of `bytesB`

```
00000000: aced 0005 7372 0011 6a61 7661 2e75 7469  ....sr..java.uti
00000010: 6c2e 4861 7368 5365 74ba 4485 9596 b8b7  l.HashSet.D.....
00000020: 3403 0000 7870 770c 0000 0002 3f40 0000  4...xpw.....?@..
00000030: 0000 0001 7400 0a61 6161 6161 6161 6161  ....t..aaaaaaaaa
00000040: 6178                                     ax
```

3rd line 6th column is the difference.

I'm on Java 11.0.3.

---

(RESOLVED)

As per Alex R's response - what happens is that HashSet's writeObject stores the `capacity`, `loadFactor`, and `size` of the backing `HashMap`, but its `readObject` recalculates the capacity as:

```java
capacity = (int)Math.min((float)size * Math.min(1.0F / loadFactor, 4.0F), 1.07374182E9F);
```

Other than a sanity check, it actually ignores the `capacity` value that was originally stored!

Comment: Probably the underlying array is a different size.

Comment: Are you referring to the bytes array or an internal array? The bytes arrays are the same size.

Comment: The underlying array in the hash set.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you create a `HashSet` using the constructor it creates a `HashMap` with a default size of 16.

If you deserialize it, the size might be initialized to be less than 16 if your set contains less entries. This is what happens in this case.

Take a look at the `readObject` implementation of `HashSet` to see how the size is calculated.

Printing the two byte arrays gives you a hint that this has happened indeed:

```
[..., 16, ...]
[..., 2,...]
```